# Testing redirect coming from a middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I have this test case:

```
public function testRedirectToAndSetDefaultLocale()
{
    $locale = config('app.locale');
    $this->visit('/')->assertRedirectedTo('/' . $locale);
    $this->assertEquals($locale, app()->getLocale());
}
```

And the following middleware:

```
class SetLocale
{
    public function __construct(Application $app, Redirector $redirector, Request $request)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->redirector = $redirector;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @param  string|null $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $locale = $request->segment(1);

        if (!array_key_exists($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.locales'))) {
            $segments = $request->segments();
            $segments[0] = $this->app->config->get('app.fallback_locale');

            return $this->redirector->to(implode('/', $segments));
        }

        $this->app->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The test case above fails with the following trace:

```
  A request to [http://localhost:8000/en] failed. Received status code [404]./Users/xxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:196
    /Users/xxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:80
    /Users/xxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:138
    /Users/xxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:80
    /Users/xxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:61
    /Users/xxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.project/tests/HomepageTests.php:17
```

I'm assuming that a server is not started or something like that. However I don't know what to do.

Edit:

Here's what I have in my `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
$locale = $this->app->request->segment(1);
$this->app->setLocale($locale);


$router->group([
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    'middleware' => 'web',
    'prefix' => $locale
], function ($router) {
    require app_path('Http/routes.php');
});
```

And in `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
    'as' => 'get.index'
]);
```

Comment: Post your routing file, apparently you have no route matching "/en" URL

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I have edited my question.

Comment: What's the value of $locale in RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: If I load `localhost:8000` and since the RouteServiceProvider is executed before the middleware it's `null`, then the middleware redirects to `/en` and then RouteServiceProvider says `locale` = `en`.

Comment: And how do you get that value in RouteServiceProvider? As routing is not defined yet, I think you can't get the locale from the URL unless you parse the URL manually

Comment: I have included that in my question. I thought I have pasted the whole thing.